# The average determinant of all integer matrices with coefficients $0,1,2$

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $S$ denote the set of $A \in M(n,\mathbb R)$ such that every entry of $A$ is either of $0$, $1$ or $2$, then is it true that $$\sum_{A \in S} \det A \ge 3^{n^2}\ ?$$

Comment: May I ask why have you reasons to believe this is true? Of course, the inequality holds for $n=1$, but I would have hold with a $3^{n^2}$ instead of $3^n$. It make more sense to me to ask whether or not $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3^{n^2}}\sum_{A\in S}\det(A)\geqslant 1$ holds. The quantity on the left side appears to be the mean value of $\det$ on $A$.

Comment: @C.Falcon : yes , I did mean that , I have edited

Answer (score 13):

No. Divide $S$ into three piles: $N, Z, P$, with negative, zero, and positive determinants. Then the sum breaks into three terms. The sum for the zero-det pile is zero. And since (for $n \ge 2$) the map that swaps the first two rows of a matrix is a bijection from $N$ to $P$, the sum of $N$ and the sum over $P$ are additive inverses of each other, and therefore the total sum of the determinants is zero.

If, however, you asked about the sum of the *absolute values* of the dets, that'd be an intriguing question.

Post-comment addition: For $ n = 1$, the claim is true.

Comment: I see , so the sum is $0$ here ..

Comment: Yes...but I should have made the condition that $n$ is at least 2. For $n = 1$, the sum is indeed $1$.

Comment: I was thinking to explore this problem like upto what limit of integers $n$ does this work? like I found that this is true for $n=0,1,2,3$ will this be true if we increase the  chain ? ,any help @JohnHughes